# How does SXS chooses which framework version should be loaded?

Tags: .net, com, manifest, sxs, registration-free-com

I'm currently working on getting .NET Assemblies (with COM classes) to work registration free.
It works well, however i have one issue which i can't seem to pin-point the exact cause.

My issue is, assembly binding isn't done on the correct .NET Framework version.

I currently have 2 assembles (let's call them A.dll and B.dll) and they are both built using .NET 4.0.

B.dll is very small, i made it to test Registration-free activation. It has a manifest next to it, B.dll.manifest). It contains 1 class with 1 property and 1 method.

A.dll is much more complex, signed, it's manifest is embeded as a resource as a post-build event (using mt.exe).

I made a VB6 application to test them. My application has a manifest, which declares the dependencies.

If i run my application, B.dll works well but A.dll doesn't. Looking at the binding logs with fuslogvw.exe, i found that the binding of A.dll is attempted using .NET 2.0, while B.dll is done using .NET 4.0.

A.dll ends up failing with error code 0x8013101b, which is COR_E_NEWER_RUNTIME.
    ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x8013101b).

To get it to work, i have to add a .config file to my VB6 application with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" >
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Then, it binds to the proper framework version and it works.

I tougth that maybe, MT.exe changed attributes/meta-informations in my Assembly, making it think it should be loaded with 2.0. So i opened it up using ILSpy. Everything i see in there talks about 4.0 and nothing is suspicious.

I've read that the assembly should be loaded, by default, using the FW that was used to build em (in my case, they are ALL 4.0, no 2.0 anywhere). So, i don't get WHY it tries to load that particular one using 2.0.

This is an issue for me as i would like to avoid having to create/maintain but most of all DEPLOY those .config for all the applications that are gonna use this particular assembly. That would mean having around 100 .config files, in my particular case.

For reference:

The MT.exe i used is from 7.0A SDK and is version 5.2.3790.2076.

Here is the fuslogvw.exe output (sorry for the french and the messed up accentuated char, the important part is the framework version number anyways)

B, working

```
JRNÂ : cette liaison dÃ©marre dans le contexte de chargement de default.
JRNÂ : tentative de tÃ©lÃ©chargement du fichier de configuration de l'application Ã  partir de file:///C:/RegFreeCom/BafComClient/binTB/Project1.exe.config.
JRNÂ : Le fichier de configuration C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\Project1.exe.config n'existe pas.
JRNÂ : aucun fichier de configuration de l'application n'a Ã©tÃ© trouvÃ©.
JRNÂ : utilisation du fichier de configuration d'hÃ´teÂ : 
JRNÂ : utilisation du fichier de configuration de l'ordinateur Ã  partir de C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
JRNÂ : stratÃ©gie non appliquÃ©e Ã  la rÃ©fÃ©rence Ã  ce stade (liaison d'assembly privÃ©e, personnalisÃ©e, partielle ou basÃ©e sur l'emplacement).
JRNÂ : tentative de tÃ©lÃ©chargement de la nouvelle URL file:///C:/RegFreeCom/BafComClient/binTB/sidebysidenet.DLL.
JRNÂ : le tÃ©lÃ©chargement de l'assembly a rÃ©ussi. Tentative d'installation du fichierÂ : C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\B.dll
JRNÂ : entrÃ©e dans la phase d'installation Ã  exÃ©cution Ã  partir de la source.
JRNÂ : le nom de l'assembly estÂ : B, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
JRNÂ : la liaison a rÃ©ussi. Elle retourne un assembly Ã  partir de C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\B.dll.
JRNÂ : l'assembly est chargÃ© dans le contexte de chargement default.
```

A, not working

```
JRNÂ : cette liaison dÃ©marre dans le contexte de chargement de default.
JRNÂ : tentative de tÃ©lÃ©chargement du fichier de configuration de l'application Ã  partir de file:///C:/RegFreeCom/BafComClient/binTB/Project1.exe.config.
JRNÂ : Le fichier de configuration C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\Project1.exe.config n'existe pas.
JRNÂ : aucun fichier de configuration de l'application n'a Ã©tÃ© trouvÃ©.
JRNÂ : utilisation du fichier de configuration de l'ordinateur Ã  partir de C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
JRNÂ : rÃ©fÃ©rence post-stratÃ©gieÂ : A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=SomeToken, processorArchitecture=MSIL
JRNÂ : Ã©chec de la recherche dans le GAC.
JRNÂ : tentative de tÃ©lÃ©chargement de la nouvelle URL file:///C:/RegFreeCom/BafComClient/binTB/A.DLL.
JRNÂ : le tÃ©lÃ©chargement de l'assembly a rÃ©ussi. Tentative d'installation du fichierÂ : C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\A.dll
JRNÂ : entrÃ©e dans la phase d'installation Ã  exÃ©cution Ã  partir de la source.
ERRÂ : erreur lors de l'extraction de l'importation du manifeste Ã  partir du fichier (hr = 0x8013101b).
ERRÂ : impossible de terminer l'installation de l'assembly (hr = 0x8013101b). DÃ©tection terminÃ©e.
```

A, working (thanks to the config file)

```
JRNÂ : cette liaison dÃ©marre dans le contexte de chargement de default.
JRNÂ : tentative de tÃ©lÃ©chargement du fichier de configuration de l'application Ã  partir de file:///C:/RegFreeCom/BafComClient/binTB/Project1.exe.Config.
JRNÂ : le fichier de configuration de l'application a Ã©tÃ© trouvÃ© (C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\Project1.exe.Config).
JRNÂ : utilisation du fichier de configuration de l'applicationÂ : C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\Project1.exe.Config
JRNÂ : utilisation du fichier de configuration d'hÃ´teÂ : 
JRNÂ : utilisation du fichier de configuration de l'ordinateur Ã  partir de C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
JRNÂ : rÃ©fÃ©rence post-stratÃ©gieÂ : A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=SomeToken, processorArchitecture=MSIL
JRNÂ : Ã©chec de la recherche dans le GAC.
JRNÂ : tentative de tÃ©lÃ©chargement de la nouvelle URL file:///C:/RegFreeCom/BafComClient/binTB/A.DLL.
JRNÂ : le tÃ©lÃ©chargement de l'assembly a rÃ©ussi. Tentative d'installation du fichierÂ : C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\A.dll
JRNÂ : entrÃ©e dans la phase d'installation Ã  exÃ©cution Ã  partir de la source.
JRNÂ : le nom de l'assembly estÂ : A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=SomeToken
JRNÂ : la liaison a rÃ©ussi. Elle retourne un assembly Ã  partir de C:\RegFreeCom\BafComClient\binTB\A.dll.
JRNÂ : l'assembly est chargÃ© dans le contexte de chargement default.
```

Comment: Thinking it may have been because of mt.exe, i modified my Post-Build Event to only generate the manifest and skip the embeding (leaving my assembly untouched). I still get the same error. Tried moving to a newer version of MT (the one that comes with SDK 8.1) and that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Found i had references in my assembly to older 2.0 assemblies. I removed them to test it out. Same result still, so references are not what's causing my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M. Miller from the CLR Team pointed me in the right direction. My manifest (generated by mt.exe from Windows SDK 7.0A) didn't include a value in the runtimeVersion of the clrClass tag.

This was causing the CLR Loader to get into a "Capped" loading path. This capped loading path, which from what M. Miller told me, happens when a version isn't v4 or higher and it caps the value returned by the loader's "FindLatestVersion" to v2. So it tries to load assemblies using the 2.0 FW.

Modifying the manifest to specify the proper version (v4.0.30319) and making sure nothing was cached (i had to copy my directory somewhere else, for the right version to appear in the logs), ended up solving my problem. Now the loading goes down the right path instead of going the "Capped" path.

So this ended up being a simple manifest issue.

FWIW, i tried generating the same manifest using mt.exe from Windows SDK 8.1 (latest one) and it generated the runtimeVersion attribute properly!

I would like to thanks Mark Miller for his help on this matter, without his help it would have taken a while for me to figure this out!

Comment: About the caching mechanism, i found this blog entry. The caching makes debugging faulty manifest really difficult. This blog entry contains a workaround 
http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/245-find-out-why-your-external-manifest-is-being-ignored

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  The key piece here was that reg-free COM was being used to register the CLSID and the manifest didn't include the version string that the shim uses to determine which runtime is appropriate.  Typical registration with RegAsm or other tools generates registry keys with the proper version string, and apparently mt.exe (at least the latest one) gets this right as well.  Note that this is the "runtime version", similar to the version strings used for the supportedRuntime configuration element, and not the "marketing versions" used for .NET (3.5, 4.5, etc.)

Comment: Yes, the latest (SDK 8.1) mt.exe's out does indeed contain the correct runtimeVersion. However, the one installed under "7.0A" does not. Just a word of warning to anyone trying to use it to generate Reg-Free COM manifests.